# Download files from a .txt or .list file containing lines of URLs

Tags: downloading

I am trying to download all files from a downloads.list file which contains about 60 lines of URL to download .deb packages from my Ubuntu computer which is not connected to the internet due to lack of wifi. I have internet access to my phone. My question is, is there an app or binary to download the URL of files listed on a .txt or .list file?

Comment: I don't think there's any app for that. You could write a shell script easily to do it.

Comment: @GokulNC actually [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags) has this capability. But I agree with you that a simple shell script is the easier and faster approach here, as long as something like `wget` is available on the device: `while read url; do wget $url; done <file.txt` (just out-of-my-head, might need some syntax polish ;)

Comment: @Izzy yeah, we can also [open the URL using browser automatically from terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488179/how-to-open-a-url-from-terminal) and let the browser manage the download

Comment: Exactly (as long as it doesn't ask dumb questions like what to do with the link/file :) Mind setting up an answer? Browser should be available on every device, shell as well, a terminal app can be installed. Of course there also might be a [Download Manager](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_downloadmanager) covering that in a GUI – I've not tried any of them.

Comment: Why didn't you use tethering to share your phone internet to Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a shell script to do it:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
while read url; do
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d $url
done < file.txt
```

This just reads each line from file.txt, opens the URL using Google Chrome Browser (using com.android.chrome package's MainActivity) and let Google Chrome manage the download.

As @Izzy said, you can also use this script to download using Download Managers, you've to just change the app package name and the corresponding Activity Name in the script.

**Edit:**
I just figured it out for [Advanced Download Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm&hl=en):

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.dv.adm/.AEditor -d $url
```

Note:
The names of application package and Activity Name are subject to change as per the developer's wish. Use it accordingly.

Comment: Ooh, and make sure the file.txt is in UNIX format (using `\n` for new line, instead of `\r\n` as in Windows format). You can use `dos2unix` to easily convert to Unix format

Comment: This is great, I've been looking for a way to simply download a file from a script.  I didn't know Chrome could be launched like this.  I don't suppose it could be told where to store the file too?